# How to customize print for data tables (codeigniter)

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove specific column from my print output. However, I dont know how to start or from where because i just downloaded the template on the internet.

I want to remove the action column:

[image]

## These are the scripts in the footer part of the view:

Screenshot of the SCRIPTS:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a new class to actions column ? If yes then add a class to it and in @media print give display:none to that class.

Comment: @NikhileshKV Where would i find that media print?

Comment: you have to add it in your css file. Refer this link : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @NikhileshKV Is this for the print method of DataTables? Sorry I am new to this print function of data tables. I am referring to printing datatables into a paper

Comment: this is for browser's print functionality in general. Are you looking for a solution to allow printing also or only for a solution to hide actions column ?

Comment: Yes, this is for print functionality in browser. Solution to hide the actions column for printing.

Answer (score 2):

@media print
{
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

This should work fine put .no-print as your class

Comment: I placed it in the css files of the template however, nothing happened and I don't know why..